# What is `height: intrinsic` in the Safari browser?

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I have some difficulties in maintaining the size of an image. From what I know, to score better for SEO we need to specify width and height in img tag. But I want to make it responsive and follow its parent so i declared both of the height and width as 100%.

`<img src="example.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />`

For Chrome, it works fine. The image maintained its ratio and not stretched. But in Safari, the image became stretched. So when I tried to adjust the height in Safari, i found this property `intrinsic` for the height that somehow fix my problem. But I don't know what is it, i've never heard of it. So what is `intrinsic`?

[image: min-intrinsic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width),

> Older webkit browsers also support the unofficial `intrinsic` value which acts the same as `max-content`.

In other words, this is the same as `height: max-content` in the latest Chrome.

Now I don't have Safari here, so I don't know if you can also use `max-content` there, so it's best to keep the `intrinsic` too, as a fallback.

By the way, size attributes in percents are deprecated since HTML5. So what you should do to make this valid is just put some numbers in the attributes and then change to what they should be (100%, max-content) with CSS.

Comment: I've tried using `max-content` and `intrinsic`, they both are giving different output. Anyhow, thank you very much for the answer and the tips!